# What is the difference between shénme 什么 and nǎ 哪?

Tags: mandarin, simplified-characters

I can not really understand the difference and found no article about it.

Example :
你叫什么名字？Nǐ jiào shénme míngzi?
他们是 哪 国人？ Tāmen shì nǎ guó rén?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

**什么 = what**.

- 你叫**什么**名字？= **What** is your name?

**哪 = which/where**.

- 他们是**哪**国人？= **Which** country do they come from?
- 他们是**哪**來的？= **Where** do they come from?

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between shénme 什么 and nǎ 哪?

It is hard to have a rule for right or wrong. In some cases, they can be exchanged with each other, in other cases, they can not.

(1) If not connected with another noun, **什么** means a thing and **哪** means a place. For example,

这是什么？ 这是苹果。

你去哪？ 我回家。

(2) Both can be connected with another noun. Sometimes they are exchangeable. For example，

你**什么时候**过生日？= **哪天**是你的生日？= When is your birthday?

(3) In some situations, **什么** points to a thing of a broad range, while **哪个** to a thing in a limited number of things.

你叫**什么**名字？= What's your name?

**哪个**名字是你的? = Which name is yours? (When looking at a list of names)

(4) For countries, always use 哪国. But for locations, you can say 哪个地方 or 什么地方。For example,

你是哪国人？ 我是美国人。= Which country are you from? I am from the USA.

你是什么地方的人？= 你是哪个地方的人？= 你的老家是哪里？= Where is your hometown?